# Adding the Comma to CSV File vb.net without messing the file order

Tags: vb.net, csv

i'm writing data into a csv file by formatting a string called newline then appending that string to a string builder called csvBill by adding an array of strings called data in the format function
my problem is if the data contains a comma it messes up the cvs file 
is there a way that i can keep the comma without it messing the data in the csv file

for examples
Chase,Inc

it shows 
Chase 
Inc

```
newline = String.Format("{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},
                        {13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21}", data)
csvBill.Append(newline)
```

after finishing the append

```
File.WriteAllText("S:\Applications\TI\CustomerBillingData.csv", 
                   csvBill.ToString())
```

Comment: If you add quotes around each value, then the values can contain commas.

Comment: Some software will allow you to use a different separator instead of comma, for example semi-colon `;`

Comment: @mrlucmorin that may be true, but applications reading Comma Separated Value files might expect commas to separate the values!

Comment: Please read this before making snotty remarks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one way I normally do it and works fine when opening the file in excel is:

```
newline = String.Format("""{1}"",""{2}"",""{3}"",""{4}""", data)
csvBill.Append(newline)
```